# How to find back "this" pointer from gcc/clang optimized code?

Tags: c++, pointers, gcc, clang, this

Under windows/VC, offset of 'this' pointer from vtable, is stored in an object's RTTI information block, which can be found by searching vtable location. This helps people to find "this" pointer in optimized code of release version.

I wish to know under linux, if gcc/clang optimizes code and "this" is not normally in fixed register or code offset, how to find it by gdb or other tools?

Comment: I'd rather recommend not to to write code relying upon such kind of trickery.

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: @ πάντα ῥεῖ : `gdb` is a very common debugger. The intent is fairly clear; this isn't intended to be used while _writing_ code; it's to _debug_ code.